# Are questions about paragliding appropriate?

Tags: discussion

I'm just starting to learn [paragliding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paragliding) and I was wondering if question on that subject would be appropriate to this site.

Comment: my personal opinion is that it would be appropriate.

Comment: I was about to ask the same question. In addition, not quite sure if there are any paragliding pilots are here to answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would say questions about paragliding (or powered paragliding / powered parachutes) are in scope - it's just an aircraft with an inflatable wing and a different control system.